# Remove elements of a list

Tags: r

I have the following list

```
n = 1:10
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) 
x = list(n, s, b, 3)
```

For a vector `v` we can remove elements like this: `v[-(1:2)]`. But how do we go about removing elements from a list? Say that I want `x` where `x[[1]]` should now have the last two elements removed - is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Writing NULL into an element effectively removes it from the list

Comment: I think your question headline could be misinterpreted as "remove elements of a list" vs. the intended "remove elements from list item that is a vector". Perhaps you could adjust your headline to make it easier for other readers to understand the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `head` to remove the last two elements of the specific `list` element by using negative index and update the `list`

```
f1 <- function(lst, ind){
           lst[[ind]] <- head(lst[[ind]], -2)
           lst
 }
f1(x, 1)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#[[2]]
#[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee"

#[[3]]
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

#[[4]]
#[1] 3
```

Or another option using `replace` in the comments by @Frank

```
f2 <- function(lst, ind) replace(lst, ind, list(head(lst[[ind]], -2)))
```

Comment: @BillyJean  That is the first case where all the `list` elements have the last 2 elements removed

Comment: In the OP I want the last 2 elements of the first vector of `x` removed

Comment: @BillyJean  That is the second case I mentioned.  If you want to apply to any element, then a function is better.  Added that

Comment: I want the list (and all the vectors it contains) returned, but for the n'th vector the last two elements should be "shaved off".

Comment: @BillyJean Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try this C# (Just substitute your values):
  [Code]

  string[] array = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };

  List<string> list = new List<string>(array);

  //you can sort List<string>!
  list.Sort();

  list.Remove("4");//remove specieifed item.
  list.RemoveAt(2);//remove item from index.
  list.RemoveRange(1, 2);//remove a range of items.

  [/Code]
```

Comment: Yeah, okay, but the question is specifically about manipulating specific data structures, so using the proper language seems important. Also, it may interest you to know that "lists" in R are not linked lists.

Comment: If v[-(1:2)] removes 1, then wouldn't it be v[-2(1:2)] would remove 2?

Comment: No, I think what you're saying is not meaningful in R, where `v[-(1:2)]` removes the first and second elements. R is indexed starting from 1, not zero.

Comment: from what I gathered in R, this removes the 5th element: and closes up the hole. myList[[5]] <- NULL

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Avoid negative result values in the length calculation (many thanks @Frank)**

To remove the last two elements of the first list item use:

```
x[[1]] <- x[[1]][seq_len(max(0, length(x[[1]]) - 2))]
```

which results in

```
> x
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[2]]
[1] "aa" "bb" "cc" "dd" "ee"

[[3]]
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

[[4]]
[1] 3
```

Note that the example `v[-(1:2)]` of the OP does **NOT** remove the **last two elements** but the first two:

```
> n[-(1:2)]
[1]  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

If you were using names for the list items the code would even be more intuitive:

```
...
x = list(n=n, s, b, 3)  # name the first list item "n"
...
x$n <- x$n[seq_len(max(0, length(x$n) - 2))]
```

If the vector has less than two elements it is shortened to a length of zero.

Comment: `1:(length(x)-y)` is dangerous for reasons that I guess you know. Safer might be seq.int(max(0, length(x)-y)) or similar.

Comment: Absolutely right, not assuming any precondition is a must. I will change it